# read multiple parquet file at once in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple parquet files categorised by id something like this:

```
/user/desktop/id=1x/year=2020/month=8/day=12/file1.parquet 
/user/desktop/id=2x/year=2020/month=8/day=15/file2.parquet 
/user/desktop/id=3x/year=2020/month=9/day=11/file3.parquet 
/user/desktop/id=4x/year=2020/month=8/day=22/file4.parquet
```

I have a python list which holds all the id value something like this:

```
id_list = ['1x','2x','3x']
```

I want to read all the files at once for ids present inside in id_list and also I want to read files which corresponds to month=8
So, for this example only file1 and file2 should be read.

I am doing like this:

```
sub_path = '/*/*/*/*.parquet'
input_df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/user/desktop/' + 'id={}'.format(*id_list) + sub_path)
```

This is picking only the file inside first id of the id_list which is id='1x'. Can anyone please help me what I am missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by all files at once? Do you want to read all files under specified id's or files specific to someday, month, year inside that id's?

Comment: @Shrey Jakhmola I want to read all files for the ids those are present inside id_list at once. For this example I should be able to read three files which belongs to id=1x,2x and 3x because is 4x is not present inside id_list but the way I am doing it's only reading one file which belongs to id-1x

Comment: And "at once"- I am trying to say, somehow, if possible -want to read all the matching files in a single line .Don't want to first create empty dataframe, loop through the ids, creating individual dataframe ,do union all these things..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by :

```
id_list = ['1x','2x','3x']
input_df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/user/desktop/').filter(col('id').isin(id_list))
```

While using the filter operation, since Spark does lazy evaluation you should have no problems with the size of the data set. The filter will be applied before any actions and only the data you are interested in will be kept in memory, thus reading only required all data or files into the memory for the IDs specified.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why col('id') ? Id is a  subfolder (/id=something/) not a column of the parquet files and also where spark will understand there are more nested subfolder(year/month/day) with out using any wild char!

Comment: getting error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: `

Comment: What input columns does it shows in the error? It should ideally contain column  `id` the the path `/user/desktop/`. It could be that are other folders other than id=x under `/user/desktop/` which might be conflicting.

Comment: Why are you filtering based on 'id'? I am not going to filter any column. I just want to read all files based on the id

Comment: I have used filter because all the IDs present in the list and passed as a list in the filter which will push down the predicate first and will only try to read the ID mentioned. Your approach to reading data under a folder has to be dynamic as well as efficient. If the folder structure `/user/Desktop/` contains folders other than partition folder `/id=(some x)/` then it is wrong to store data in such a partition scheme.

Comment: Kindly read about reading and writing partitions in spark [here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partitionby/). You need to understand how partitioning works in Spark and how it affects the reading, writing, and underlying structure of folder and data.

Comment: Actually I am not understanding your solution. Where is the sub_path = '/*/*/*/*.parquet' ? Can you please write down the full ans ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221984/discussion-between-shrey-jakhmola-and-ppari1).

Answer (score 0):

This will exactly load those path which have id specified in id_list and month=8

```
id_list = ['1x','2x','3x']
path = "/user/desktop/id={id}/year=2020/month=8/*/*"
paths = list(map(lambda idx: path.format(idx), id_list))
spark =  SparkSession.builder.appName("sample_app").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(paths)
```